# How to turn HTML form input into Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm making a new game, I want the amount of circles in the game to be inputed by the player, but am having difficulty setting up the variable from HTML into javascript.

I have determined that the problem only relies on the 'i' variable not being set correctly, since replacing 'document.getElementsByName('circles').value;' with any number works fine.

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="number" Name="circles" id = "circles" min="2" max="50" 
        value="2">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800">
    </canvas>
</div>

<script> 
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i = document.getElementsByName('circles').value;
for (i; i > 0; i= i-1) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(Math.random()*c.width+1, Math.random()*c.height+1, 25, 0, 2 * 
    Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
```

I expect the number of appearing circles to be the same as the given value, but instead nothing happens.

Comment: Why use `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementById`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get value by id not using names and make input type as button not submit.

```js
function a(){
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i = document.getElementById('circles').value;
console.log(i)
for (i; i > 0; i= i-1) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(Math.random()*c.width+1, Math.random()*c.height+1, 25, 0, 2 * 
    Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}}
```

```html
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="number" Name="circles" id = "circles" min="2" max="50"/>
        <input type="button" onclick='a()' value="Click"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell more , because on printing the value of i, I am getting the same value which i input in the input box

Comment: the value of "i" is actually what you input in the text field called "circles". I guess it does comply with what you said.